# DataGrid Exception Handling

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, datagrid

I have been stuck with this for hours and hope somebody can shed some light on this. Say I have a `DataGrid` control:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RealEstates, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          Name="grdData_RealEstate" 
          Margin="5,5,5,5"
          Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
          RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}">
</DataGrid>
```

Which is bound to a propetry that exposes the RealEstates table of a `DataSet`.

Now when the user deletes a row from this table I would like to perform some checks before allowing or denying the delete. 
What I have done is to subscribe to the `RowDeleting` event of the DataTable.

```
workingDataSet.Tables["realestates"].RowDeleting += Database_RowDeleting;
```

Then in the method that handles it, I just throw an exception. The actual logic will follow once I get this working.

```
void Database_RowDeleting(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    throw (new Exception("Can't delete"));            
}
```

This works and raises the exception when I am trying to delete any row from the `DataGrid`. The problem though is that the `DataGrid` control is not catching the exception (red border the `DataGrid` control) which causes my program to shut down and is obviously not what I want. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? How can I get the `DataGrid` to catch these exceptions?

Comment: The simple answer is you can't easily catch it. For that reason throwing Exceptions from event handlers in C# is generally not a good idea. Instead simply feed the result of the delete into a custom EventArgs class, or raise DeleteSucceeded / DeleteFailed events as required.

Comment: @Octopoid: Not exactly sure what you meant with you proposed solution but you placed me on the right track with your statement to avoid throwing exceptions inside event handlers. I think I have a solution now, will test it and place it as the answer if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have a solution for anybody else interested.

I subscribed to both the `RowDeleting` and `RowDeleted` events of the `DataTable`:

```
workingDataSet.Tables["realestates"].RowDeleting += Database_RowDeleting;
workingDataSet.Tables["realestates"].RowDeleted += Database_RowDeleted;
```

Then I created a field to allow or deny the delete:

```
bool allowRowDelete;
```

Next I perform my validation logic inside the `RowDeleting` method:

```
void Database_RowDeleting(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    allowRowDelete = true;

    if (Convert.ToUInt32(e.Row["id"]) > 3)
        allowRowDelete = false;
}
```

Then in the `RowDeleted` method I reject the delete if the validation failed:

```
void Database_RowDeleted(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{            
    if (!allowRowDelete)
        e.Row.RejectChanges();
}
```

Although this is an answer to this question it's not my preffered solution since I originally wanted to use Foreign Key Constraints as in one of my other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444386/handle-constraint-exceptions-in-datagrid) this will have to do for now.

Some other post, that people with this same problem might find interesting:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-stop-a-change-in-the-rowdeleting-event-handler.1239208/

[What is the "pressed the delete key" event for the WPF Datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677326/what-is-the-pressed-the-delete-key-event-for-the-wpf-datagrid)

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21758199.html

http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/39077

Comment: Inside your `RowDeleting` event handler you should just be able to set `e.Cancel = true;` to cancel the delete from continuing.

Comment: Now that would have made much more sense, but turns out `DataRowChangeEventArgs` does not have such a member. It only provides the 'Action' which was taken (obviously delete) and the row upon which this action was performed.

Comment: My mistake - wrong sort of data grid row! As you say, `e.Cancel` would have been nice and neat, but your solution is absolutely fine anyway.